# url rewriting using jsessionid in query string is not working for post method

Tags: session, servlets, url-rewriting

While using query string for url rewriting in the form with jsessionid for the POST method in the servlet which I have mapped, I am not getting the same session id when the cookies are disabled. I know that it will not work for the GET method but I learned it will work for the POST method, is it correct.

```
String jsessionid = session.getId();
  out.println("<form action='servlet2?jsessionid=" + jsessionid + "' method='post'>");

  out.println("Age:<input type='text' name='age'/><br>");
  out.println("Email:<input type='text' name='email'/><br>");
  out.println("<input type='submit' value='submit'/>");
  out.println("</form>");
```

here I am setting the jsessionid in the url using post method.

```
HttpSession session = r1.getSession();
```

In next servet2 I am getting the different session id.
Can I get same session id in url rewriting with jsessionid for post method.

Answer (score -1):

In Servlet2, You can instead do something like this :

```
String jsessionid = request.getParameter("jsessionid");
```